# Consider defining a bean of type 'com.test.project.repositories.TaskRepository' in your configuration @Repository annotation is already there

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-redis

I am building a basic spring boot application with Redis as the data store. I have followed all the general spring-data-redit tutorials and doing everything exactly like here. 
https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/persistence-modules/spring-data-redis

But when I start the application, I end up in this error.

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field taskRepository in com.test.project.services.TaskService required a bean of type 'com.test.project.repositories.TaskRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.test.project.repositories.TaskRepository' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have been looking for a solution for a few hours now. I have tried component scanning the whole package.

IntelliJ is able to locate the bean from @EnableRedisRepositories annotation. You know the green button on the left. But when the application is run, it doesn't.

I am using spring boot and spring boot data 2.1.3.RELEASE

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The actual object

```
@RedisHash("KnapsackTask")
@Data
@Log
public class KnapsackTask extends Task implements Serializable {

    Problem problem;
    Solution solution;


    public KnapsackTask(Problem problem) {
        this.problem        = problem;
        this.timestamps     = new Timestamps();
        this.timestamps     .setSubmitted((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L));
    }

    public KnapsackTask(String taskId) {
        this.taskId = taskId;
    }

    public KnapsackTask submit() {
        log.info(problem.getCapacity().toString());
        problem.getValues().forEach(p -> log.info(p.toString()));
        problem.getWeights().forEach(p -> log.info(p.toString()));
        log.info(this.taskId);
        log.info(this.getStatus().toString());
        return this;
    }

    public KnapsackTask process() {
        return this;
    }

    public KnapsackTask complete() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Service Class that is autowiring the repository

```
@Service
public class TaskService {

    @Autowired
    TaskRepository taskRepository;

    public Task submitTask(Task task) {
        task.submit();
        task.generateNewTaskId();
        task.setStatus(Task.Status.SUBMITTED);
        taskRepository.save(task);
        return task;
    }

    public Task processTask(Task task) {
        task.process();
        task.setStatus(Task.Status.STARTED);
        taskRepository.save(task);
        return task;
    }

    public Task completeTask(Task task) {
        task.complete();
        task.setStatus(Task.Status.COMPLETED);
        taskRepository.save(task);
        return task;
    }

    public Task getTask(String taskId) {
        return taskRepository.findById(taskId).get();
    }


    public class TaskNotFound extends RuntimeException {

    }
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface TaskRepository extends CrudRepository<Task, String> {

}
```

Redis configuration file

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories(basePackages = "com.test.project.repositories")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        return new JedisConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<>(Object.class));
        return template;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your repository class's package name?

Comment: com.test.project.repositories

Comment: this seems to be related: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-mongodb/issues/20

Comment: Is your main application class located in a package above e.g. the main package? The @SpringBootApplication annotation only scans for components below.

Comment: package com.test.project is the main package which is where @SpringBootApplication is. 

package com.test.project.repositories is where the repository is.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after hours of endless debugging I was able to resolve the issue.

```
@Repository
public interface TaskRepository extends CrudRepository<Task, String> {}
```

The Task class was declared abstract for some other reason and the Repository was not being registered in the context because of that.

Hope it helps someone else.